# Pulling values from different columns depending on an input

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm building a weekly variance report. I have all the values I need (sales, labor, profit, etc.) in a sheet that is organized in 4 columns by Week 1,2,3,4.

In another sheet I have a report I want to populate, but, depending on what week I am currently in, I want it to only pull the values from that corresponding week's information.

For instance in Week 1, I want it to pull all the values from Week 1's sales, labor, etc. But in Week 2, I want it to pull from the column beside it instead (Week 2).

How can this be done?

Comment: Sample data may be helpful perhaps....

Answer (score 0):

The function required to achieve this is `VLOOKUP()`.  The following demonstrates how you might use this function for your particular situation.

Set up two worksheets like this

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

and this

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `D2`  of `Sheet2` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-right into the rest of the row:

```dart
=VLOOKUP(D$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$E$4,1+RIGHT($B$2,1),FALSE)
```

Note that this formula will also work if the value in `Sheet2!B2` is just a number.

You will, of course, need to adapt the formula to suit your report. In particular, you could hard-code the value of the first argument of `VLOOKUP()` so the formula doesn't require a header.